# Can I place QGIS layer scope action button to my own toolbar?

Tags: qgis, python, toolbar

When I create QgsAction for layer in python code it placed as submenu for "Action" button [image].
Can't find way to place it like QAction in some other toolbar.

```
from qgis.core import QgsAction
actionText="from qgis.utils import iface\nlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('[% @layer_id %]')\nif layer:\n  if len('[% $id %]')>0:\n    feature = layer.getFeature( [% $id %] )\n    iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feature, True)"
editFormAction = QgsAction(QgsAction.GenericPython, 'Open edit form', actionText, pluginDir + "/Icons/FormEdit.svg", False, 'Open edit form', {'Feature', 'Canvas'}, '')
layer.actions().addAction(editFormAction)
```